# get Custom Field Type

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to get the type of the custom fields I declared for the user...

```
int type = user.getExpandoBridge().getAttributeType(attribute);
```

The fact is that the function returns an Integer. There's any place where I can find the match between the identifiers(int type) and their type names?

Thank you,
Oriol

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `ExpandoColumnConstants.*` ([javadoc](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/expando/model/ExpandoColumnConstants.html))

Comment: I watched this javadoc before... But what about if I created an Integer(64Bits) or Text CustomField?? ExpandoColumnConstants are not the same as Types available at the time of creating Custom Fields! If I created a CustomField with Type Text, I want to get Text Type.